# Unable to zipalign apk android android studio 2.2

Tags: android, google-play, apk, zipalign

I am publishing my app using android studio 2.2 preview 3 and generating signed apk. But when i am uploading apk to google play i am getting error

```
You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.
```

Also i tried to used zipalign tool manually but i am getting error verification failed.
Here is my build.gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "blackdogs.newaomsi"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        zipAlignEnabled true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


    }
}}
```

Comment: What's the oputput of `zipalign -c -v 4 yourapk.apk`?

Comment: @antonio 
 5379164 resources.arsc (OK)
Verification FAILED

Comment: Then your apk is not zipaligned. Could you try executing `zipalign -f -v 4 yourapk.apk yourzipalignedapk.apk` and then `zipalign -c -v 4 yourzipalignedapk.apk`?

Comment: @antonio Tried as u said still getting the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it. Error was due to gradle version i was using.
Downgraded gradle version to

```
 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3, as explained in [this blog post](http://blog.goddchen.de/2016/06/android-gradle-plugin-2-2-0-alpha3-is-missing-zipalign/) and [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212591).

You have to download Preview 2 or use the stable version of Android Studio.

Comment: finally ended up installing 2.1 in parallel

Answer (score 1):

solved in the next release

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**2.2.0-alpha4**'

reference link:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212591